# Python - how to check if the value is within given range of float/integer?

Tags: python

Why this is not working?

```
reflace=0
input = "55,1,1,1".split(",")

# Now find the first field from comma
input[reflace] = round( float( input[reflace] ) , 2) + 0.01
ranges = [(-1,1)]
if any(lower <= input[reflace] <= upper for (lower, upper) in ranges):
  print "+ " + input
```

not printing

Comment: since 55.01 is greater than 1 :)

Comment: Is this code intentionally obfuscated?

Comment: This is because all of your values in `input` are outside the inclusive interval [-1, 1], which causes your `any(…)` to fail, thus never executing the `print` inside the `if`

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the string from `input` to something else. I am using `inputData`.

```
reflace=0
inputData = "55,1,1,1".split(",")
# Now find the first field from comma
inputData[reflace] = round( float( inputData[reflace] ) , 2) + 0.01

print inputData[reflace] ### Will print 55.01

ranges = [(-1,1)]
if any(lower <= inputData[reflace] <= upper for (lower, upper) in ranges):
  print "+ " + inputData
```

So, you are checking whether 55.01 is in the range of -1, 1. That is not true. Thats why nothing is getting printed.